# How to plot a row as a line in GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I have seen similar questions asked a few years ago but the answers basically involved transposing the data before plotting.  As GNUPLOT is evolving maybe there is a simpler way to handle this today?

My data are composition profiles at different time steps during a simulation.  Each line represent the composition of an element at a specific time at different points in space and I would like to plot this row by row, in the simplest case just a single row as this

```
plot '-' using ?:? with lines ls 1
 0.310 0.318 0.334 0.364 0.413 0.476 0.532 0.569 0.588 0.595

e
```

As the simulation may take several hours (days) it would be nice to be able to see how the profiles evolve just by making the simulator generate such a row at certain time steps. For a snapshot at a specific time I could of course write the values in a column and "plot '-' using 0:1" but as I want to save several snapshots in the same file it is simpler to have each profile as a row, not just as an extremely long file with a single value at each row.
At the end I will be interested in plotting all the profiles at the saved time steps but then I could of course transpose the profile matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a strict matrix (i.e. equal number of columns for each row), then you could plot a row like the following:

**Code:**

```
### plotting rows
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 0.310 0.318 0.334 0.364 0.413 0.476 0.532 0.569 0.588 0.595
 1.310 1.318 1.334 1.364 1.413 1.476 1.532 1.569 1.588 1.595
 2.310 2.318 2.334 2.364 2.413 2.476 2.532 2.569 2.588 2.595
 3.310 3.318 3.334 3.364 3.413 3.476 3.532 3.569 3.588 3.595
EOD

myRow = 2     # counting starts from 0
set key left

plot $Data matrix u 1:3 every :::myRow::myRow w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti sprintf("Row number %d",myRow)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is cryptic but I will test.

Comment: @BoSundman does this work for you? You might want to have a look here: Plotting one row versus another row. Even more cryptic ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744418/7295599

Comment: It works well for me thank you.  Each row I have to plot is a time step so I do not need to plot a row relative to another.  But I do not understand those ::: etc in the answer, GNUPLOT is really powerful but, as I wrote, quite cryptic.  Luckily there is stackowerflow when the manual is not sufficient.

Comment: @BoSundman If this answer solved your problem, please check the answer as helfpul/acceptable. Check the manual `help every`. I agree, in some cases the documentation could be improved, especially with practical real-life examples. In case of "normal" column data `every` is setting step,start,end of points and blocks. But with the option `matrix` it apparently is setting step,start,end of columns and rows.